# DATASTAGE ODBC query get current_timestamp

Tags: sql

Estou a fazer um job no datastage e quando insiro a query no ODBC preciso do current timestamp, sendo que me passa sempre para null ao escrever na tabela. 
Já utilizei `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, `(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)`, `'#CURRENT_TIMESTAMP#'`, etc..

Segue a query.

```
(INSERT INTO dev_dw.compress_log VALUES ('#ORIGIN_TABLE#' , '#DESTINATION_TABLE#', '#CONDITION#' , CURRENT_TIMESTAMP )).
```

Alguém consegue ajudar-me?

---

Criei uma table em parquet no hive, ao executar o job não consigo inserir o current_timestamp na tabela que criei.

---

```
INSERT INTO dev_dw.compress_log VALUES ('#ORIGIN_TABLE#' , 
    '#DESTINATION_TABLE#', '#CONDITION#' , CURRENT_TIMESTAMP )
```

Comment: Está um pouco confuso cara, você consegue explicar um pouco melhor?

Comment: Qual o banco, SQL Server?

Comment: Criei uma table em parquet no hive, ao executar o job não consigo inserir o current_timestamp na tabela que criei.

Answer (score -1):

Boa noite!
Você pode fazer um insert passando uma coluna nova a partir de um transformer com a função CurrentTime()